# Can we say that an element is not a subset of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am creating a multiple choices question for students that should be as follows:

Which of the following is true?

1) $8\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

2) $8\notin \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

3) $8\subset \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

4) $8 \not\subset \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

Should choices Number (1) and (4) be considered as valid answers?
My understanding is that we can't deal with an element with either $\subset$ or $\not\subset$.

Please give me references supporting your answer if there.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA How about $\varnothing\in\{\varnothing\}$ and $\varnothing\subset\{\varnothing\}$ then?

Comment: @drhab Yes, that's allowed. What's not allowed is for members to intersect the containing set. The intersection of $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ is empty so it's OK.

Comment: @skyking: Consider $X=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$. The member $\{\varnothing\}$ intersects $X$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good, counter example (I was mistaken).

Comment: I have seen a handful of elementary textbooks with this exact problem and the correct answer has always been **(1) and (4)**.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Just because something is in a textbook doesn't mean it's right. Further more the issue here is one of notation and definition so it depends on what else is in the book. As drhab points out it's quite possible for (3) to be correct depending on your axioms and definitions.

Comment: @DRF I never made a claim that the textbooks were "correct", it was only intended to be a gauge of how other author's have treated this topic.

Comment: @JaredGoguen: Your first comment is misleading to most students. Your second comment does not justify it because how other authors treat this question is irrelevant to the correct answers.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, an element of a set can be a subset of that set.

Think of $\varnothing\in\{\varnothing\}$ and $\varnothing\subset\{\varnothing\}$, where $\varnothing$ denotes the empty set.

The answer to your multiple choice question depends on how $\mathbb Z_+$ and $8$ are defined.

A possible construction exists with $\mathbb Z_+=\{1,2,3,\dots,8,\dots\}$ and $8=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.

In that case $8\in\mathbb Z_+$ and $8\subset\mathbb Z_+$.

Comment: Well, this is _possible_, but it would be a strange construction, because the set named $8$ would then have _seven_ elements. In the usual Von Neumann construction of the integers within set theory we have $8=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, which, because it has $0$ as an element, is not a subset of $\mathbb Z_+$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I admit: indeed strange, but possible. In my construction (adapted to the question that was asked, dealing with positive integers) $1=\varnothing$ and we do not have to bother about $0$ which does not belong to $\mathbb Z_+$

Comment: But in your construction how is $8 \in \mathbb Z_+$?

Comment: @Ant $\mathbb Z_+$ is defined here as the intersection of all sets $A$ that contain $1:=\varnothing$ as element and satisfy $n\in A\implies n\cup\{n\}\in A$. It can be proved that $8:=\{1,2,\dots,7\}$ is one of these sets. As Henning remarked it is unusual, but it works.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to initiate a class discussion on what "8" might mean to a mathematician and whether $A \not \subset B$ means the same as $\neg (A \subset B)$ when A or B is not even a set (or is everything in mathematics built from a set anyway ?), then this is a great way to start.

If you wish to leave those topics until another occasion then I suggest you change the question !

Comment: This is a very good point -- I think everyone else (myself included) had overlooked that the OP is the teacher rather than a student who has already been given this question.

Comment: I would add that using a multiple-choice test to stimulate classroom discussion is likely to be rather unpopular in a system where students view tests primarily as a way to earn grades by showing what they _have_ learned, rather than an opportunity to learn further.

Answer (score 2):

The easy answer is that only option 1 (and possibly 4) is true, that's enough for naive set theory.

Note that even if $8$ is not a set the construct $8\subset\mathbb Z^+$ is a well-formed statement (the only problem is that it's false, only sets can be subsets). The statement 4 is true in the sense that it's the negation of $3$, but in naive set theory one could also use the definition that such statements being false as $8$ is not a set.

Comment: x @skyking: You were probably thinking of the _Axiom of Regularity_. However, in addition to not having the consequence you thought it had, it is not there to avoid paradoxes (introducing an additional axiom can never make a contradiction go away) -- it is there mostly for tidiness and for the technical convenience of allowing $\in$-induction to prove things about all sets. (For example, with the axiom we can be sure that every set has a rank).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes it was that axiom. I think it was a good decision to omit the last paragraph rather than to try to fix it...

Answer (score -3):

For me the option 1 is valid, for options 3 and 4 proper notation of set isn't used. If we require to represent a set with elements then the elements should be surrounded by curly braces . Hence 8 doesn't represents a set therefore 3 and 4 options are invalid.

This wikipedia [post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)) suggests the notation used for set elements