# If $A$ is an element of $B$ does that imply that $A$ is a subset of $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Question:** Suppose that $A\in B$, does this imply that $A\subset B$? If so, why?

I have tried to look at using the following example:

Suppose that $A = 4$ and $B = \{4\}$. We definitely have $A \in B$, but I'm not sure whether this implies $A\subset B$, since $A$ is not even a set, but a number.

I read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2243189/can-we-say-that-an-element-is-not-a-subset-of-a-set) that an element of a set *can* be a subset of a set. But I don't think that it mentions $A\in B \Rightarrow A\subset B$.

Comment: A set $B$ with the property that every element of $B$ is a subset of $B$ is called a *transitive* set, not to be confused with the idea of a transitive *relation*. They are called transitive sets because the property "every element of $B$ is a subset of $B$" can be expressed by saying "$x\in y\in B$ implies $x\in B$", as if the relation $\in$ were transitive. Transitive sets are very special, and they play a certain role in the foundations of set theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct all the way through. $A\in B$ does not imply $A\subseteq B$ (and indeed $4\in\{4\}$ but the only subsets of $\{4\}$ are: $\emptyset$ and the whole set $\{4\}$).

Sometimes something can be an element of a set and a subset of it, e.g. $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset\}$ and $\emptyset\subseteq\{\emptyset\}$, though (unless you are a set theorist) this is more of a curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally wrong. If $A$ is an element of $B$, then we can write $B= \{A,\ldots\}$.

A set $A$ is a SUBSET of a set $B$ iff each element $x$ of $A$ is also an element of $B$.

In your case, $A$ is a subset of $B$ would require that $A$ is an element of $A$; the latter would be a cyclic definition of a set: $A=\{A,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This property is one of the properties defining *ordinals*, in von Neumann's definition:

it is a set $X$ such that

1. The relation $\in$ on elements of $X$ is a *strict order* and $X$ is *well-ordered* by this relation.
2. $X$ is *transitive*, i.e. $\;\forall x\in X, \:x\subset X$.

For instance, natural numbers are ordinals, and their set $\mathbf N$ is the first transfinite ordinal. Transfinite ordinals  are particularly useful for proofs by *transfinite induction*.

*Elementary examples of this situation*: a construction of the set of natural numbers:

$0$ being defined as $\varnothing$, $\; 1=\{\varnothing\}$, $\:2=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$, $\:3=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\}$, &c.

Comment: I think this is far beyond the level the asker needs to be helped at.

Comment: Probably. I just wanted to show this property does exist in real maths.

Comment: @Bernard A 'real math' – I like it! :)

Comment: As opposed to properties designed just for school problems.

Comment: @Bernard I meant, there's no 'real math', maths is abstraction only. There's no such thing (I mean a _real_ thing) like, e.g. the number one. You can have one apple or one car, you can have one planet or one electron, but you can't have 'the' **1** itself. There's no such thing like a line, either - there are pencil strokes on paper and finger-drawn grooves on sand, and there are beams of laser light in a dusty air - but they all are somewhat thick and somewhat curved, and all have finite length. Same with any mathematical concept or notion - they're all abstract, none is 'real'. :)

Comment: @CiaPan: What is real depends on whether you're a platonist or not anyway. Reality is not only in things you can own. Is a poem real?